# Serialise observable next function calls

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Consider the following Typescript / rxjs code:

```
import { range } from 'rxjs'; 

range(1, 5).subscribe(async (num) => {
  await longLastingOperation(num);
})

function longLastingOperation(num) {
  console.log('starting', num);

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('done with', num);
      resolve();
    }, Math.random() * 1000);
  });
}
```

Each emitted value triggers a long lasting operation of a random duration. the console output is unpredictable and looks something similar to this:

```
starting 1
starting 2
starting 3
starting 4
starting 5
done with 2
done with 5
done with 1
done with 4
done with 3
```

Now, I want to "serialise" the execution of the long lasting operations for each emitted value. For instance, I want that `longLastingOperation(2)` waits for `longLastingOperation(1)` is done before it starts.

I'd like to achieve an output every time looking exactly like that:

```
starting 1
done with 1
starting 2
done with 2
starting 3
done with 3
starting 4
done with 4
starting 5
done with 5
```

How would one achieve this with rxjs and observables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `concatMap` operator on each `longLastingOperation(num)` call to wrap response in Observable and subscribe to results in order:

```
range(1, 5)
.concatMap((num) => {
  return Observable.fromPromise(longLastingOperation(num));
})
.subscribe(res => {
  console.log(`End working on ${res}`) // Shall be ordered here
})
```

Here is documentation reference:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap

Here is some my additional work on this topic:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/rx-map-misleading-marbles-tomasz-budzi%C5%84ski/

Comment: Glad I was able to help. For your reference, please have look on http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#operators and section `Choose an operator`. It will point out operator you need in 95% of cases. Unfortunately, RxJS 6 does not have this feature on it's doc site :(